# Internet connection problems after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, internet, dns

Today I upgraded Ubuntu to 18.04 and now I have almost no internet. When I try to open a site in *firefox*, I usually get error 'unable to connect'.

Oddly I can connect to some sites (google, some local news site,… ). I used to have `dnsmasq` instead of `systemd-resolved`. Now `dnsmasq` doesn't want to start:

```
> (error: "failed to create listening socket for port 53: Address already in use.")
```

If I disable `dnsmasq` and use `systemd-resolved` it runs, but problem is not solved. What to do?

Comment: Do you only have that problem with Firefox, or also with other programs?

Comment: In Network Manager it says Connected, but I don't get notification, that I'mconnected after restarting Network manager. I only use firefox.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I deleted profile of my ethernet connection and new connection worked

Comment: I have the similar problem, but yours not worked 4 me. Just I had discovered the problem occurred after ssh login into my server, then I could browse my website on that server only through https and so http urls not working no longer!!!